# Can a variable be used as a key for a named parameter in the dart language?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is what I want to do:

```
My constructor
Item({this.id})

Creating an Item
Item(ItemFields.id: 'abc')
```

It seems like I have to do it like this though:

```
Item(id: 'abc')
```

I'd prefer to not hard code my parameter names like this if I can avoid it.

Comment: Can you expand more on why you wouldn't want to do this? Or how the other method would be more beneficial?

Comment: Say I have a database table of items and I want to change the field name from id to identifier. I then have to go search through all my code in all my code bases on the keyword "id" and update it everywhere which is a PIA. If I can parameterize it then I can just use like an enum or whatever in place of a hardcoded string which makes refactoring way easier. Same reason why I avoid use dot property access on objects in favor of [] because I can parameterize the [] method of property access.

I like to design as I go without getting punished for changing my mind on how I name stuff.

Comment: Understood... To my best knowledge you cant do what the question asks in `dart`. A nod to the old saying *"There are only two hard problems in computer science, cache invalidation and naming things"* :P. You can however look into `code_generation` and see if that can help you.

Comment: "Say I have a database table of items and I want to change the field name from id to identifier. I then have to go search through all my code in all my code bases on the keyword "id" and update it everywhere..." Maybe that's something you want, but it's not something you *have* to do.  The name of the database field and the name of the variable you use to store that field in your code are independent.

Comment: @jamesdlin If I'm reading data from a database then sure I can store the "id" field in some variable or container object with a field of my choosing that's not called "id". But when I go to insert the data back into the database I need to call it "id" again. And I'll face the hard coding problem I'm talking about.

Example: 
    DocumentReference<Item> doc = await itemsRef.add(Item(
      id: itemsRef.doc(),
      locationID: projectID,
      zoneID: zoneID,
      sectionID: sectionID,
      name: name,
    ));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar to what you want is possible with `dart:mirrors`, but it has a few drawbacks:

1. Doesn't work on all platforms (notably, doesn't work at all in Flutter)
2. (related to 1) Prevents tree-shaking, since all code can be executed through reflection in a way that is not analyzable at compile-time
3. The API is unstable

If your main concern with this is to do with renaming, as your comment suggests, most IDEs allow you to rename a symbol, renaming all occurrences. In VSCode, the shortcut is F2, in Android Studio it is Shift+F6.